# Selecting records from monday 4 weeks ago

Tags: mysql

I have this query which selects the last 4 weeks of records from my table:

```
SELECT * FROM activity 
  WHERE dateAdded 
  BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 4 WEEK) AND now()
  ORDER BY activity ASC;
```

However I would like to select the last 4 weeks of records starting from the Monday 4 weeks ago regardless of the current day.

Also, the query does not seem to select todays record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.

```
SELECT * FROM activity 
  WHERE 
  YEARWEEK(`dateAdded`, 1) = YEARWEEK(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 WEEK), 1)
  ORDER BY activity ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `SELECT * FROM activity 
  WHERE dateAdded 
  BETWEEN date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 4 DAY),INTERVAL 4 WEEK) AND date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
  ORDER BY activity ASC;`